# cmake cant find the eigen3 package

Tags: compiling

I got this cmake error after eigen3.2 installation in a software install procedure, is there any clear suggestion to fix it?

```
-VirtualBox:~/ceres_build$ cmake . ../ceres-solver/ -DMINIGLOG=ON -DBUILD_TESTING=OFF -DBUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.5.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.5.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Detected Ceres being used as a git submodule, adding commit hook for Gerrit to: /home/ceres-solver/.git
-- Detected Ceres version: 2.0.0 from /home/ceres-solver/include/ceres/version.h
-- Detected available Ceres threading models: [CXX_THREADS, OPENMP, NO_THREADS]
-- Building with C++14
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:242 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Eigen3" (requested
  version 3.3) with any of the following names:

    Eigen3Config.cmake
    eigen3-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Eigen3" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Eigen3_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Eigen3"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/ceres_build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to install [development package for Eigen3](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=Eigen3Config.cmake) by

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get install libeigen3-dev
```

and retry.

Also please note that [Ceres itself](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/libceres-dev) is included into Ubuntu repositories. You have to install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install libceres-dev
```

so you do not need to compile it by yourself.

Comment: Thanks, it helps a lot.