# I am getting error as Eigen3 not found

Tags: system-installation

I am getting error as Eigen3 not installed but Eigen3 already installed with updated version.
can any one help me to resolve this issue.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: If you installed an Eigen3 version not from the repositories, you might be on your own. Could you describe how you installed it? (For better reading, add the info into your Question, **not** in a comment)

Comment: @kanehekili ,i have installed Eigen3 using command sudo apt install libeigen3-dev is there any specific steps to install then pls let me know so i can follow those steps

Comment: Since you didn't follow the instructions from @kanehekili ([Edit] your question, don't Add comment) I have no confidence that you will follow instructions to fix your problem. Why should we try to help you?

Comment: Hi @waltinator  i am not  able to edit my question because getting error as min.10 reputation required. this is the reason i am not followed instruction from@ 
kanehekili

Comment: That question should have been answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1265526/cmake-cant-find-the-eigen3-package) Did you try that?

Comment: @kanehekili  thanks for responce it works for me. after cleaning my build directory and followed  your steps.